# Add buttons to GridView rows dynamically

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview which is being populated by a Javascript. Now after this action I want to add Start and Stop buttons to the data that has already being bound via the Javascript. So the final Gridview row would consist of 2 buttons and the column values that have been set by the Javascript.Can someone please suggest

Comment: Why is this question tagged ASP.NET? Please post the relevant code you have for creating the table. Also, you should accept some of the answers you have received to your other questions.

Comment: This is related to Gridview hence this has been tagged as ASP.NET